# Getting the key from a value within a dict of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of dicts `dict_of_dicts={1:{'id':1,'name':'joe'},2: {'id':2,'name':'jim'},3: {'id':3,'name':'bob'}}` (the structure is out of my control so I cannot define my dict more conveniently). I am looking to extract the id # (which also corresponds to the key of the upper dict) of the sub dict containing `'name':'bob'`. i.e I want to extract the id value for a specific name.

I have thought of a looping solution, but is there a more pythonic way to go about this? My attempt is below

```
for i in list(dict_of_dicts.values()):
    if i['name']=='bob':
        print(i['id'])
```

Comment: You don't need `list()`, a for loop works on any iterator including `dict.values()`

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution you can try out,

```
search_ = 'bob'

for k, v in dict_of_dicts.items():
    if search_ in v.values():
        print(f"Id {k}")
        break
else:
    print("No Match Found")
```

---

**Edit**

```
def search_(key):
    for k, v in dict_of_dicts.items():
        if key in v.values():
            return k
        
    return -1  # Indicating no match found
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the regex format in the first print statement? I actually want to return the id as an int in a function but I used print in the example as it's an easy function to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
for k, v in dict_of_dicts.items():
    if v["name"] == "bob":
       print(v["id"])
```

You can also just `print(k)`

Comment: Valid comment, I have deleted it from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the structure is out of your control, in case you want to have multiple searches, it might make sense to reformat the data before searchign multiple times, you can match the results later again if needed:

```
d = {1:{'id':1,'name':'joe'},2: {'id':2,'name':'jim'},3: {'id':3,'name':'bob'}}

n = {e['name']:e['id'] for e in d.values()}

n.get('bob')
#Out[32]: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use `filter` function by passing a lambda that resolves to `True` if the name matches the search criteria. I passed in a default value of `{'id': None}` when grabbing the first item using `next` item if there are no match.

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: x['name'] == 'bob', dict_of_dicts.values())
match = next(filtered, {'id': None})
print(match['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner:

```
d={1:{'id':1,'name':'joe'},2: {'id':2,'name':'jim'},3: {'id':3,'name':'bob'}}

print ([ k for k,v in d.items() if 'bob' in v['name'] ])
```

Output:

```
[3]
```

Here you get a list of keys/id in case you have multiple ids with `'name':'bob'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *next()* to find the first instance in a generator that satisfy your needs:

```
dict_of_dicts = {
    1: {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'joe'
    },
    2: {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'jim'
    },
    3: {
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'bob'
    }
}

# Find "bob"
try:
    id_bob = next(
        dict_of_dicts[key]["id"]
        for key in dict_of_dicts
        if dict_of_dicts[key]["name"] == "bob"
    )
except StopIteration:
    print("'bob' not found, handle this some way")
    raise

# bob_id == 3
```

If you know for sure that `"id"` is the same value as the `key`, just use `key` instead of `dict_of_dicts[key]["id"]`.